# Does KFC serve chicken?

Tags: nutrition, biology

There are rumors that the meat [KFC](http://www.kfc.com/) serves is not permitted to be labelled as chicken.

> Kentucky Fried Chicken has become KFC. Does anybody know why? We thought the real reason was because of the "FRIED" food issue. It's not. The reason why they call it KFC is because they can not use the word chicken anymore. Why? KFC does not use real chickens. They actually use genetically manipulated organisms.
>
> These so called "chickens" are kept alive by tubes inserted into their bodies to pump blood and nutrients throughout their structure. They have no beaks, no feathers, and no feet. Their bone structure is dramatically shrunk to get more meat out of them. This is great for KFC because they do not have to pay so much for their production costs. There is no more plucking of the feathers or the removal of the beaks and feet.
>
> The government has told them to change all of their menus so they do not say chicken anywhere. If you look closely you will notice this. Listen to their commercials, I guarantee you will not see or hear the word chicken. I find this matter to be very disturbing. I hope people will start to realize this and let other people know.

- [Viral email via UrbanLegends.About.com](http://urbanlegends.about.com/od/fooddrink/a/kfc_chicken.htm) - which attempts to refute it.

Are KFC serving real chicken?

Comment: The link you provide does a reasonably good job of rebutting the claim that KFC is made from something other than chicken or from engineered mutant creatures in a lab, but apart from one sentence at the end it doesn't make the claim that KFC is *safe*.  Could you edit your question to clarify exactly which claim you want examined (mutant chickens or that KFC is safe)?  A definition of *safe* would be required if you want the latter examined.

Comment: As above, please edit to *either* ask "Is KFC made of chicken?" or edit it to ask "Is KFC safe to eat?" AND add a notable source of the claim that it isn't safe to eat.

Comment: @Oddthinking If I have a notable source for this issue, why should I come and ask here? Why should I ask something I can answer myself? I read the source that I provided and I couldn't make a decision.

Comment: @Mawia not notable source of the answer, but notable source of the claim. Not the same thing.

Comment: I've edited the question to focus on what they are serving, rather than the more broad "Is what they are serving safe?"

Comment: I know for a fact that in Quebec they use local chicken and the norm are strict enough. Also, how a genecally manipulated chicken would be less chicken than one breeded and selected by human to possess better characteristics (controlled evolution)?

Answer (score 17):

Claim's completely bonkers, as they still use the full name everywhere (just look at the facades of every single KFC franchise out there). It's just easier to use shorthand for things where limited space is available.
http://colonelsanders.com/ history of KFC, the video explicitly uses the word 'chicken'.
http://colonelsanders.com/history_colonelSanders.asp uses the word 'chicken' liberally from the first paragraph.

> Kentucky Fried Chicken, pioneered by Colonel Harland Sanders, has
>   grown to become one of the largest quick service food service systems
>   in the world - with more than a billion “finger lickin' good” Kentucky
>   Fried Chicken dinners served annually in more than 80 countries and
>   territories. But success didn't come easily.

http://www.kfc.com/about/franchises.asp talks about

> Based in Louisville, KY, KFC Corporation is the world's most popular chicken franchise specializing in Original Recipe®, Kentucky Grilled Chicken® and Extra Crispy Strips® with home-style sides, Honey BBQ Wings and freshly made chicken sandwiches. KFC has been serving customers complete, freshly prepared, family meals since Colonel Harland Sanders founded the concept in 1952.

and that's just the first paragraph.

http://www.kfc.com/ mentions chicken explicitly in the product descriptions it offers.

The photo on the current http://www.kfc.com/about/news/ page shows the word "chicken" still being used on a store-front.

[image]

The fact that this is a recent photo can be inferred from the fact that it's shown with a [post-2007 version of their logo](http://www.famouslogos.us/kfc-logo/).

In other words, there's no truth to the claim that KFC don't use the word chicken. If indeed they did not use chicken, they'd indeed not be allowed to use the word. Hence the claim that they don't use chicken is bogus.

Comment: Plus, even if their chickens were transgenics, they would still be chickens. Clearly whoever wrote that does not have a clue about what a transgenic animal is.

Comment: @nico true, from the text of the claim I assumed they were claiming KFC is using some sort of protein substance generated in a test tube, like that "artificial meat burger" that made waves last month.

Comment: Your assertion that *"just look at the facades of every single KFC franchise out there"* is not correct. All UK KFC's are branded KFC not Kentucky Fried Chicken. eg, http://www.tripadvisor.co.uk/Restaurant_Review-g190727-d2456866-Reviews-KFC_Kentucky_Fried_Chicken-Poole_Dorset_England.html

Comment: @Jamiec I've never seen one like that, but could be some use the logo only for some reason (maybe because they don't want to be associated with the US for example, which I can imagine in some places like Iran or parts of the UK).

Comment: @jwenting I think the first company able to make a 100% non-animal meat indistinguible from the animal meat would make a lot of noise publicizing that, and a lot of money in the process.

Comment: [Design and History of KFC Logo](http://www.famouslogos.us/kfc-logo/) says, "In 1991 the company unveiled a new logo with the abbreviation “KFC” as a measure to distinguish the restaurant as a healthier eating choice."

Comment: @jwenting There's no need to "assume they were claiming" when you can read the referenced claim in its entirety. That is one of the benefits of having a reference to a published claim in the OP! I edited the OP to quote a little more.

Comment: Anecdotal, I always read that they changed to KFC in the UK to disassociate themselves from the word "Fried" which is seen as unhealthy.

Comment: @ChrisW yes, but that doesn't mean they removed the full name from their restaurants or other promotional material, let alone stopped using the word 'chicken'. If you check their website, there's recent photos of franchises listing the full name.

Comment: I see the word "chicken" but don't see a photo on the pages which you linked to in your answer. Perhaps you'd like to add one.

Comment: @ChrisW http://www.kfc.com/about/news/ look at the "franchising" header. Also http://www.kfcfranchise.com/ which links from there.

Comment: I posted the photo: I expect that this is "fair use".

Comment: I was going to go with the line that the menu names and descriptions use the word 'chicken', but this question doesn't deserve two answers. This one is perfectly adequate.

Comment: @Nico - I have read claims that the "chicken" is has been modified to not have a head feet or feathers and is "fed" intravenously and that it was not really chicken genetics that formed the base of it...  I know where some of the farms are that raise the real chickens for them in the midwest so I know it is not the case but I have read those claims.

Comment: @Chad I've read those, as well as claims that they're serving yeast products flavoured to taste like chicken (guess those guys read too much science fiction), and anything in between.

Comment: @Duralumin so do I, but that's not how the conspiracy theorists think. And this is a conspiracy theory so we have to debunk their kind of "reasoning".

Comment: @Chad: that is exactly what I am saying... whoever comes up with those factoids should first read a biology book. Probably one targeted to primary school should suffice...

Comment: Actually you could theoretically engineer an organism like that.  I do not think that we are there with our knowledge or our abilities to execute such a concept on a commercial scale when you consider that a whole chicken can be born and raised in 16 weeks for about $1.50

Comment: It is by no means clear that "if indeed they did not use chicken, they'd indeed not be allowed to use the word." Perhaps in the description of a particular food product, but that has nothing to do with the name of the company. They serve many things that are not chicken (cole slaw, for example). Also, the "Kentucky" in the name of the company does not guarantee that any ingredients are from that state.

Comment: @LarryGritz the claim is they don't use the name because they're not allowed to for not serving chicken... As they use the name, that debunks the claim whether they serve chicken or not (and they state they do, so that debunks your claim as well, as stating they serve chicken when they don't is not allowed).

Comment: @jwenting I agree that if they call a certain meal chicken, food labeling laws come into play. I'm just saying that you can't infer the ingredients from the name of the company. Can you clarify? Is there a statute that says that you must do what the company name says?  Starbuck's Coffee Company sells many drinks that don't contain coffee. If they discontinued sale of coffee entirely, focusing on other parts of their menu, would they have to change the company name? Or would they merely have to avoid incorrectly labeling actual tea that they sold as if it were coffee?

Comment: @LarryGritz In the UK a butcher shop was fined for selling "dragon sausage" because it didn't contain dragon meat (not joking). Would they have to change their name if they stopped selling chicken altogether? Possibly, though I doubt there's enough commonality in law to state so for the entire planet. It's however irrelevant to the claim (in fact the reverse of the claim), but an interesting mental exercise if you have the time and energy to go through hundreds of legal texts.

Comment: @jwenting If you sell a specific MEAL ITEM called "chicken", it had better be chicken, or all sorts of laws come into play. But just because "chicken" is in the COMPANY NAME doesn't mean they are obligated to sell chicken, any more than "Kentucky" obligates them to have any connection to that state. Company names are just names (except for a few special cases designated by law, like calling yourself a "bank"). This observation breaks the basic premise of the question, which is that changing the company name would be some kind of evidence one way or the other about their ingredients.

Comment: @LarryGritz that would depend on the legal framework in place. You'd have to show that such is the case in every country where KFC has a presence.